# Privilege escalation if the privileged ID is known

Tags: linux, operating-systems

If I know the ID of a group, whose privilege is higher than mine, is it possible for me to execute programs using that group ID? If so, how do I do it? If not, why not?

Will appreciate all answers.

Comment: You may use ``sudo`` to launch apps as another user (say, root). What do you mean by "privilege is higher than mine"?

Comment: Say there are directories that only that group is permitted to access, but I can't. However, I know the group's ID. How can I use this ID to access the directories too?

Answer (score 1):

Not if the system has been designed properly. For example, Linux groups have IDs which are sequential, so there may be groups with IDs going from 500 to 510. That doesn't mean you can just become a member of one of those groups though. If you could, so could anyone who guesses at other group IDs, which would render the security of the system worthless.

It would be possible that a bug in the system implementation resulted in users being able to join arbitrary groups, but any such bug would hopefully be fixed quickly, so while it's not impossible as a concept, practically, it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has security protections around calls to [setgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgid.2.html) that prevent you from just assuming another group because you know its GID:

> setgid() sets the effective group ID of the calling process.  If the caller is privileged (has the CAP_SETGID capability), the real GID and saved set-group-ID are also set.

While there are special circumstances involving things like the [setgid setting on an executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_executables), generally only root has access to this permission.

There are commands such as [su(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) that allow you to become another user (and group if the user is in a different group than the current user). These commands run as root and have security checks (typically they require the destination user's password) to make sure that you have permission to login as that user.

If the security of setgid relied on knowing the GID, it would be an example of [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), a well-known security anti-pattern.